# ClassCastException при использовании View Pager

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Использую NavigationTabDrawer и ViewPager для приложения.
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.default_preview);
        NavigationTabBar navigationTabBar = (NavigationTabBar) findViewById(R.id.ntb_horizontal);
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new PlayerFragment();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new StatisticFragment();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        fragment = new HeroesFragment();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        fragment = new MatchFragment();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        fragment = new GuildFragment();
                        break;
                }
               return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 5;
            }
        });
        final ArrayList<NavigationTabBar.Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
        models.add(
                new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_first),
                        Color.parseColor(colors[0]))
                        .selectedIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sixth))
                        .title("Heart")
                        .build()
        );
        models.add(
                new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_second),
                        Color.parseColor(colors[1]))                         .selectedIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_eighth))
                        .title("Cup")
                        .build()
        );
        models.add(
                new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_third),
                        Color.parseColor(colors[2]))
                        .selectedIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_seventh))
                        .title("Diploma")
                        .build()
        );
        models.add(
                new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fourth),
                        Color.parseColor(colors[3]))                   .selectedIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_eighth))
                        .title("Flag")
                        .build()
        );
        models.add(
                new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fifth),
                        Color.parseColor(colors[4]))
                        .selectedIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_eighth))
                        .title("Medal")
                        .build()
        );

        navigationTabBar.setModels(models);
        navigationTabBar.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(final int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#1f1c22"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="475dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <devlight.io.library.ntb.NavigationTabBar
        android:id="@+id/ntb_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:ntb_badge_gravity="top"
        app:ntb_badge_position="right"
        app:ntb_badged="true"
        app:ntb_scaled="true"
        app:ntb_tinted="true"
        app:ntb_title_mode="active"
        app:ntb_titled="true"
        app:ntb_swiped="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

При запуске приложения вылетает ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main   Process: ru.spoketplace.vainstatistic, PID: 1020 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Можете показать на какую строку ругается? Похоже, что у вас указаны неверные типы в определении ресурсов.